# List of ISIN for Options, Swaps, Derivatives?

Tags: options, finance

In pages like isin.org or openfigi you can search by an ISIN and you will get information about the share, bond, fund...

However, for options , derivatives the search returns 0 results. Is there a web similar to the ones mentioned with a list of ISIN for these securities?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a complement to Adam N. the [ESMA](https://www.esma.europa.eu/) (the EU market regolatory body) is providing its **huge open database of financial instruments** (all sorts, with 6 million derivatives or so), **called [firds](https://registers.esma.europa.eu/publication/searchRegister?core=esma_registers_firds_files), free of charge**. You can **consult it online** and **download the whole database** or its updates.

You can see an example (the first column is the ISIN):

[image]

The limitation is that these are products traded in Europe; but it so happens that a good chunk of non-European instruments are traded on European venues, anyway so there are chances that ESMA knows about them.

For your information, the download files are classified according to the CFI classes. For **derivatives**: F for futures, S Swaps, O for options, etc.  This is a massive amount of data in XML format, so if you are willing to use them, be prepared!

Answer (score 3):

This is rather a comment than an answer:

From my understanding, you might find ISINs for exchange traded derivatives, like stock index options. For the other more or less OTC-traded products, there is usually no ISIN available for these are, well, bilaterally traded. Usually, you would rather not find “that” swaption, but benchmark quotes that are compiled by brokers and submitted to Bloomberg, Reuters etc.

Answer (score 2):

ISINs may exist for some derivatives, in particular exchange-traded derivatives. But they are not very useful: For one, they are not usually used by market participants. More importantly, they often do not suffice to describe a derivative uniquely. An example: the Euro-Bund Future, traded at the Eurex, has an ISIN (DE0009652644). But the ISIN stays the same, independent of the contract's expiry date. (See 
http://www.eurexchange.com/exchange-en/products/int/fix/government-bonds/Euro-Bund-Futures/14770 .)

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of MiFIR in the EU, certain OTC derivatives that are "traded on a trading venue" are to be reported to the authorities and that includes giving those instruments an ISIN.

Those are provided by [ANNA-DSB](http://www.anna-web.org/home/derivatives-service-bureau/). If you subscribe to their service, you can generate (for a fee) or download ISINs for swaps, options, forwards etc.