# Finding ISIN of current/past futures

Tags: futures, sp500

Where can I find the ISIN of futures on say SP500 eg ESM20? Is there a way to retrieve ISINs for past futures contracts?

Comment: Partally duplicates this question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37590/list-of-isin-for-options-swaps-derivatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no one assigns ISINs to CME futures.

One some other exchanges, an ISIN is assigned to the entire class of futures with different expiries.

Comment: So there's no unique identifier for a CME futures beyond something like ESM20?

Comment: Directly from the horse's mouth: https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sp-500-esg-futures-frequently-asked-questions.html#codes :)

Comment: Ok but now on ANNA ( https://www.anna-web.org/ ) I was able to find ISINs for the most recent expiries of CME futures. Where do these ISINs come from then?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Does ANNA explain who assigned it? Do you see it, e.g. on https://www.openfigi.com/ ? Would a Bloomberg terminal recognize these ISINs?